# using circom to count 0s in an array of input signal

Tags: circom

I tried to count the number of 0s in an array of input signal using circom.

```
template cnt(N) {
  signal input x[N];
  signal output y;
  var s[N];
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    s[i] = x[i] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    sum += s[i];
  }
  y <== sum;
}

component main = cnt(5);
```

The compiler said `Non quadratic constraints are not allowed!` at `y <== sum;`  But when I changed the above code from `var` to `signal`, the code compiled.  I don't understand why changing a declaration from `var` to `signal` allows my code to compile. Can anyone explain the difference here?

```
template cnt(N) {
  signal input x[N];
  signal output y;
  signal s[N];
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    s[i] <-- x[i] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    sum += s[i];
  }
  y <== sum;
}

component main = cnt(5);
```

Moreover, even the above code compiles but the number of constraints is 0.  Does having zero constraints means there is nothing to prove?  So should I use the following code, which has 10 non-linear constraints?

```
pragma circom 2.1.8;

include "comparators.circom";

template cnt(N) {
  signal input x[N];
  signal output y;
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var v = IsZero()(x[i]);
    sum += v;
  }
  y <== sum;
}

component main = cnt(5);
```